# ¿Cómo ordenar esta consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito ordenar una tabla en función de 3 columnas. Actualmente está ordenado por idioma y luego por servidor, y funciona muy bien. Al querer ordenarlo por un tercer parámetro más, no funciona. La consulta actual es:

```
SELECT * FROM enlaces where capitulo = $rt and estado = 1 and tipo='online' and servidor != '' ORDER by FIELD(idioma,'lat','es','sub','in','cat'),servidor ASC, id ASC
```

Como digo, esta consulta ordena por idiomas con un orden y luego dentro de cada idioma ordena por la categoría servidores haciendo que el resultado sea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quiero agregar otro parámetro que puede tener valores 1 o 2. La columna se llama **cpremium**, y me interesa que se ordene primero cuando es 2 y luego por 1. He intentado hacer esto:

```
SELECT * FROM enlaces where capitulo = $rt and estado = 1 and tipo='online' and servidor != '' ORDER by FIELD(idioma,'lat','es','sub','in','cat'),servidor ASC, id ASC, cpremium DESC
```

Pero al imprimir en pantalla no se ordena por este último parámetro, es como si no existiese. Por ejemplo, en la imagen de antes, en las 2 primeras filas está de colaborador *Jeferi* y *Felix*. Bien, pues *Felix* debería salir el primero, ya que él tiene en la columna *cpremium* el valor 2 y *Jeferi* el valor 1. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás ordenando por `id` (me imagino que es un valor único) antes de ordenar por `cpremium`. De modo que, en efecto, es como si no ordenaras por `cpremium` en absoluto.

```
ORDER by FIELD(idioma,'lat','es','sub','in','cat'),
         servidor ASC, 
         id ASC, -- aquí está el problema
         cpremium DESC
```

Para solucionar el problema, simplemente necesitas ordenar por `cpremium` antes de `id`:

```
ORDER by FIELD(idioma,'lat','es','sub','in','cat'),
         servidor ASC, 
         cpremium DESC,
         id ASC -- debes dejar este campo de último
```

Comment: Hola, lo probé y lo he vuelto a probar pero no me funciona como debe salir... no consigo imprimirlo bien con la consulta: SELECT * FROM enlaces where capitulo = $rt and estado = 1 and tipo='online' and servidor != '' ORDER by FIELD(idioma,'lat','es','sub','in','cat'),servidor ASC, cpremium DESC, id ASC Es como si no lo tuviese en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

He simplificado tu consulta un poco simplemente con los campos necesarios para el filtro. Para ello, me he creado una nueva tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Servidores(id int PRIMARY KEY,
             Idioma varchar(255),
             Servidor varchar(255),
             Colaborador varchar(255),
             cpremium  varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Servidores VALUES (1, 'lat', 'Gamovideo','FelixX', 2);
INSERT INTO Servidores VALUES (2, 'lat', 'FlashX','FelixX', 2);
INSERT INTO Servidores VALUES (3, 'lat', 'iDoWatch','FelixX', 2);
INSERT INTO Servidores VALUES (4, 'es', 'FlashX','jeferi chacon', 1);
```

Y utilizando la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Servidores WHERE Servidor != "" ORDER BY FIELD(idioma,'lat','es','sub','in','cat'),Servidor ASC, id ASC, cpremium DESC
```

los valores me han salido correctamente como se puede apreciar en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto, intenta cambiar de orden los filtros para ver si el problema está en que hay algún filtro con más prioridad que los otros. Como puedes comprobar a mí me funciona bien con tus filtros.

He usado la siguiente [página](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43c659a/2/0) para la consulta.

**EDIT:** Realmente en mi consulta anterior se estaba mostrando el último `jeferi chacon` debido a que había sido al único que le había puesto 'es' como idioma y el ID más ascendente.

En este caso, tendrías que ordenar por ID el último, tal y como te han comentado en las respuestas anteriores:

```
SELECT * FROM Servidores WHERE Servidor != "" ORDER BY FIELD(idioma,'lat','es','sub','in','cat'),Servidor ASC, cpremium DESC, id ASC
```

con el consecuente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9aa8/2/0) a la nueva consulta.

Comment: Para comprobar el error, necesitas comparar registros que tengan el mismo valor para `idioma` y `servidor`. Si no, el `ORDER BY` nunca considera las columnas después de `servidor`.

Comment: @sstan Sí, en eso estaba, algo me parecía raro y cometí el fallo de poner el último a jeferi y encima asignarle otro idioma. Justo cuando me has puesto el comentario estaba editando la respuesta. Muchas gracias por avisar de todas formas.

Comment: @sstan No entiendo, ¿A que te refieres con el mismo valor? Creo que has dado en el clavo porque es justo después de la columna servidor donde no lo toma en cuenta. Me he cercionado que las columnas servidor e idioma tienen el mismo valor. No entiendo que ocurre entonces.

Comment: @Ángel Fijate en las consultas. Cambia simplemente el filtro de ID al final. Mira en las dos imágenes. En la primera me había confundido porque no había puesto el mismo idioma ni un ID superior para `jeferi` pero en la segunda consulta puedes ver con los datos modificados que al cambiar el filtro de ID funciona correctamente.

Comment: @Error404 Debo ser un renegado, mira, te muestro los resultados que me retorna la sql haciendo la consulta poniendo cpremium DESC antes que id ASC:

https://i.gyazo.com/aab91ba061d6538f620774965c9958a8.png

Te he puesto las columnas afectadas a la izquierda para que se pueda ver mejor y organizado. El primer registro devuelve cpremium 1 siendo jeferi y el segundo es Felixx con cpremium 2. 

¿Es posible que te pueda dar mi correo/skype y lo veamos juntos? Entiendo tu esfuerzo y serás recomepnsado si lo solucionamos :)

Comment: @Error404 Perdón, esta es la consulta definitiva: https://i.gyazo.com/85f7f535bb0c8ea516facfa5fe46831e.png Se me olvidó poner ASC a servidor.

Comment: @Ángel ¿Con la última consulta también te sale errónea?¿Que valores te aparecen para esta última consulta?

Comment: @Error404 Con Servidor ASC, me salen estos resultados: https://i.gyazo.com/287def6cfb32e2e563165d358150f3ea.png

Comment: @Ángel ¿Has puesto `cpremium DESC`?

Comment: @error404 ¡Ya encontré la solución! ¿Como puedo hacer para hacerlo saber o marcarlo como resuelto?. Luego me dices como agradecerte toda la ayuda. Y también como hago saber a todos los que han participado que está resulto y decirles que hice.

Comment: Hola @Ángel. Me alegro muchísimo de que hayas resuelto tu duda. Para marcar que te han sido de utilidad las respuestas tienes unas flechas a la izquierda de cada respuesta. Marcándola hacía arriba indicarás que te ha sido de utilidad. Para marcar la pregunta como resuelta tienes un tick a la izquierda de cada respuesta también. Sin embargo, sólo podrás marcar este tick en una de las respuestas, la que te ha resuelto por completo tu duda. En caso de que no sean ninguna de las respuestas  actuales y sea otra respuesta diferente puedes crear la tuya propia con lo que has realizado y aceptarla.

Answer (score 0):

Ordénalas antes por `cpremium DESC` que por `id ASC` probablemente el primer registro de tu lista de "jeferi" tenga una id menor que la del segundo registro "felix".

Intenta hacerlo de esta forma, alterando el orden entre cpremium e id:

```
FIELD(idioma,'lat','es','sub','in','cat'),servidor ASC, cpremium DESC, id ASC
```

Comment: Hola, lo probé y lo he vuelto a probar pero no me funciona como debe salir... no consigo imprimirlo bien con la consulta: 

SELECT * FROM enlaces where capitulo = $rt and estado = 1 and tipo='online' and servidor != '' ORDER by FIELD(idioma,'lat','es','sub','in','cat'),servidor ASC, cpremium DESC, id ASC

Es como si no lo tuviese en cuenta